# How do I have VS recognize an existing icon?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

VS 2019, I add an existing icon (x.ico) --- Properties => Resources.resx => (right click) Open => Resources.resx. --- I drag and drop x.ico into Resources.resx.

The x.ico now appears under Resources.resx\Resources.Designer.cs\Resources.

I place the x.ico name into:

```
<Window x:Class="x.MainWindow"
   ...
   Icon="x.ico"
>
```

This is how I've done it in the past.

There are no errors when I compile.  However when I run it => IOException: Cannot locate resource 'x.ico'.

Comment: You should use pack URI to get this icon or retrieve it using resource stream

Comment: Did you try to set the `Build Action` of the `.ico` in the `Resources` folder to `Resource`? Try to do this, build and then set the `Icon` property to `resources/x.ico`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to convert the .ico to .png.  This works:

Project Name (right click) => Properties => Application (left side) => Icon => Browse to the existing .ico.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this isn't working is that WPF doesn't like ICO files. If you want to use ICOs, you will need to load the ICO from resources in code, convert it, and then set the Icon property in code.

However, if you change your icon into a `PNG`, then your original approach will work.

Your XAML will look like this:

```
Icon="Resources/x.png"
```

And like the commenters mentioned, make sure that `x.png` in the `Resources` folder has its build action set to `Resource`.

Comment: What is the procedure to convert the .ico to .png?  I created the .ico with VS 2013.  I have upgraded to VS 2019.

Comment: There are free ICO to PNG converters on the web. Just search for ICO to PNG and you'll see them.